# Phrase clustering by URL

Tags: php, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to understand and write code for clustering search queries based on common urls. We need to compare each element of the array with each by url, and if they have common URLs, then combine them into a group. Wrote a simple script, but it eats a lot of memory. Please tell me how can I accomplish this task. Maybe there are some ready-made libraries?

There is an array words of the form, example:

```
[0] => array(
 "word" => "wardrobe in the bedroom",
 "id" => 1,
 "urls" => array(
 [0] => url_1,
 [1] => url_2,
 [3] => url_3,
 [4] => url_4,
 [5] => url_5)
),
[1] => array(
 "word" => "wardrobe in the living room",
 "id" => 2,
 "urls" => array(
 [0] => url_1,
 [1] => url_2,
 [3] => url_3,
 [4] => url_4,
 [5] => url_5)
),
[2] => array(
 "word" => "white wardrobe in the bedroom",
 "id" => 3,
 "urls" => array(
 [0] => url_1,
 [1] => url_2,
 [3] => url_3,
 [4] => url_4,
 [5] => url_5)
)
...
```

I wrote such code. The simplest algorithm: we take the first phrase, and loop through each element. If there are matches, we remove them from the common array and restart the function. But eats a lot of RAM.

```
function cluster($words, $group = array())
{
    $first_elem = array_shift($words);
    $first_group = $first_elem['id'];

    $array_urls = $first_elem['urls'];
    
    foreach ($words as $i=>$data)
    {
        $check = array_intersect_key($array_urls, $data['urls']);
        
        if(count($check) >= 3)
        {
            $group[$first_group][$i] = $data['word'];
            
            unset($words[$i]);
        }
    }


    if(!empty($words)) return cluster($words, $group);

    return $group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce RAM usage, I suggest to use [**yield**](https://iwconnect.com/understanding-php-generators-memory-performance/) in 2 places:
First in looping over $words in the foreach and second try to implement array_intersect_key by your own and use yield there to loop over arrays.